Galaxy Tab Active 3's talk back accessibility feature will not turn off
We have some locked down tablet leased out for our truck drivers to use. Every now and then, one of them will accidentally activate the talk back feature. We do not have access to the settings menu of the tablet to turn it off. I learned a few months ago that you could just hold both volume buttons to disable this feature which worked for a while, but is now not fixing the problem.
Does anyone know how to turn off the talk back screen reading feature without going into the settings menu?

Possible duplicate: Accidentally turned on TalkBack, how do I turn it off?
